# How I can get source type from HTML5 video YouTube?

Tags: html, video, youtube

I have a question. I need get type of HTML5 video on YouTube(ex. video/webm or video/ogg), but I don't see tag source inside tag video and can't get by `getAttribute`. The method `canPlayType` isn't suitable.

Who anyone know to get it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something like the exemple:

```
<video id="sampleMovie" src="http://www.youtube.com/"></video>
```